# How can I track many elements that are rendered asynchronously using nightwatch and selenium?

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I just started to use NightWatch JS and Selenium, I'm trying to get the time that some charts take to be visible, but the commands get executed sequentially so I cannot get the real time that those elements take to be visible.
I'm also have developed asynchronous functions and i'm still getting the same result.

```
module.exports = {

'@tags': ['Testing'],
'Testing': function(browser) {
    console.log(browser)
    browser
    .url('someURL')
    .waitForElementVisible('input[name="username"]',10000)
    .click('input[name="username"]')
    .setValue('input[name="username"]', '************')
    .click('input[type="password"]')
    .setValue('input[type="password"]', '*********')
    .pause(2000)
    .click('button[id="btn_signin"]')
    .pause(10000)
    .isLogAvailable()
    .waitForElementVisible('button[title="My content"]')
    .click('button[title="My content"]')
    .pause(10000)
    .waitForElementVisible('div[title="Country"]')
    .click('div[title="Country"]', function(){
        browser.expect.element('g[clip-path="url(#_raveLibId_0_clipViewport)"]').visible
        browser.expect.element('g[clip-path="url(#_raveLibId_1_clipViewport)"]').visible
    })
}
};
```

Comment: You have already set long pauses but have you tried with even longer ones? You could also carefully watch the test while executing and check that all the expected clicks really happen.

Comment: Oh I see, I just left code unuseful there, the problem is over the last click, It supposes to trigger to commands, and those are executed sequentially and I also have written async functions for those and the result still being the same.